# Error because of a comment, which should actually not influence my program in python

Tags: python

Take the code below:

```
"""
\u
"""
print("hello")
```

The comment is causing the following error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

If I use `#` for the comment instead of `""" ... """` I don't get this error:

I tried searching online, but the only thing I found was that `\U` actually has a special function. In this case however, it is only a comment so **why does it influence my program?**
If I write `"""\t"""` there is no such error.

Answer (score 5):

That's a triple-quoted string, not a comment. You may have seen these in other .py files. An unnamed string at the top of a module becomes its "doc string" and can be accessed via the global `__doc__` variable or seen in `help(mymodule)`. As a string, it follows the normal python string literal rule where a `\u...` starts a unicode escape sequence.

If you want a comment, use `#`

```
# \u
```

But if you want a doc string, you could start the string with an "r" to make it an raw string where backslash escapes are ignored - or just avoid string escapes completely

```
r"""
\u
"""
```

The intent is that this string describe the module to others, so make it short and descriptive.

mymodule.py:

```
r"""This program does the most
amazing things with \u
"""
```

When run in the shell

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> help(mymodule)

Help on module mymodule:

NAME
    mymodule

DESCRIPTION
    This program does the most
    amazing things with \u

FILE
    /home/td/tmp/f/mymodule.py
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the triple quoted text (docstring) you used to mimic comment is actually being evaluated.

For example, if you open Python interpreter and type a comment, nothing will appear:

```py
>>> # hello
>>>
```

But if you type a string, the string is evaluated (and the default behavior is to print the string to stdout):

```py
>>> "hello"
'hello'
```

In your case, Python tries to evaluate `"""\u"""`, but this is incomplete since `\u` marks the beginning of a Unicode character for 16-bit (`\uXXXX`) or 32-bit (`\uXXXXXXXX`). So the error you're getting means that you didn't finish typing your Unicode character.

```py
>>> "\u2705"
'✅'
```

The problem doesn't happen with `\t` because it is a valid escape sequence just as it is, meaning a horizontal tabulation (indent right)

Comment: "evaluated" might be a better choice of words than "executed". Code is executed, expressions are evaluated (to a value). It's also worth noting that the first sentence is _technically_ not true - lone strings written in a module never get evaluated at runtime. They get parsed with the rest of the module, but they don't make it to the bytecode, and so are never actually constructed at runtime. You can confirm this yourself using the `dis` module to view the bytecode generated for statements with a lone string literal mixed in.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this, you're right that the word should be "evaluated", I'll edit the answer. And about the use in a module, even though they are not constructed at runtime, a module with `"""hello\u"""; a = 1; "hello\u"; b = 2` raises  the unicode error for the docstring and for the lone string.

Comment: Exactly, they're still parsed, so the syntax needs to be valid or else you'll get that syntax error. But they don't get evaluated to an actual string object at runtime.